# d365 plugin error An unexpected error occurred from ISV code

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

Hello coders of the world,

I'm writing my first d365 plugin and I'm encountering a problem. When I save my form, nothing happens.

I'm registered the plugin on the Quote Product entity for calculating "VAT amount" (Update message, Post Operation). I have a related "VAT" entity, which contains an integer. The plugin retrieves this integer and turns into a decimal (which represents a percentage). The VAT amount is calculated by multiplying this decimal by the amount in Quote Product:

```
decimal amountVatExcluded = baseAmount - discount;
decimal vatAmount = amountVatExcluded * vatPercentage;
decimal amountVatIncluded = amountVatExcluded + vatAmount;
```

When I debug the plugin, an error is thrown at line 41,

```
 decimal vatPercentage = GetVatPercentage(quoteLine, service);
```

which declares a variable by retrtieving a decimal from a method GetVarPercentage:

```
private decimal GetVatPercentage(Entity quoteLine, IOrganizationService service)
        {
            Guid vatId = (Guid)quoteLine.Attributes["capdcx_valueaddedtax"];
            ColumnSet attributesVatEntity = new ColumnSet("capdcx_valueaddedtaxpercentage");

            Entity vatEntity = service.Retrieve("capdcx_valueaddedtax", vatId, attributesVatEntity);
         

            decimal vatPercentageAsWholeNumber = 0;
            if (vatEntity.Attributes.Contains("capdcx_valueaddedtaxpercentage"))
            {
                vatPercentageAsWholeNumber = (decimal)vatEntity.Attributes["capdcx_valueaddedtaxpercentage"];
            }
            
            decimal vatPercentage = vatPercentageAsWholeNumber / 100;
            return vatPercentage;
        }
```

I can't fingure out what's wrong with this retrieval of the VatPercentage decimal. Any thoughts? Bewlow is the full code:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            #region pluginbase
            ITracingService tracing = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
                serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
                (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            #endregion

            #region attributes
            tracing.Trace("Obtaining Target (quoteLine) entity and attributes");
            
            Entity quoteLine = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            ColumnSet attributesQuoteline = new ColumnSet(new string[]
            {
                "baseamount",
                "manualdiscountamount",
                "capdcx_valueaddedtax"
            });

            service.Retrieve("quotedetail", quoteLine.Id, attributesQuoteline);
            #endregion

            //access related VAT entity, get its integer and turn it into decimal for percentage
            decimal vatPercentage = GetVatPercentage(quoteLine, service);

            //define price, discount, and final price without VAT
            decimal baseAmount = 0;
            if (quoteLine.Attributes.Contains("baseamount"))
            {
                baseAmount = (decimal)quoteLine.Attributes["baseamount"];
            }

            decimal discount = 0; 
            if (quoteLine.Attributes.Contains("manualdiscountamount"))
            {
                discount = (decimal)quoteLine.Attributes["manualdiscountamount"];
            }


            decimal amountVatExcluded = baseAmount - discount;
            decimal vatAmount = amountVatExcluded * vatPercentage;
            decimal amountVatIncluded = amountVatExcluded + vatAmount;

            var quotelineUpdated = new Entity(quoteLine.LogicalName, quoteLine.Id);
            quotelineUpdated.Attributes["capdcx_valueaddedtaxexcluded"] = new Money(amountVatExcluded);
            quotelineUpdated.Attributes["capdcx_valueaddedtax"] = new Money(vatAmount);
            quotelineUpdated.Attributes["extendedamount"] = new Money(amountVatIncluded);

            service.Update(quotelineUpdated);
            tracing.Trace("Succesfully set amounts of quoteLine");
            // onCreate en onSave
        }


        private decimal GetVatPercentage(Entity quoteLine, IOrganizationService service)
        {
            Guid vatId = (Guid)quoteLine["capdcx_valueaddedtax"];
            ColumnSet attributesVatEntity = new ColumnSet(new string[]
            {
                "capdcx_valueaddedtaxpercentage"
            });
            Entity vatEntity = service.Retrieve("capdcx_valueaddedtax", vatId, attributesVatEntity);
            //Entity vatEntity = service.Retrieve("capdcx_valueaddedtax", (Guid)quoteLine["capdcx_valueaddedtax"], new ColumnSet("capdcx_valueaddedtaxpercentage"));

            decimal vatPercentageAsWholeNumber = 0;
            if (vatEntity.Attributes.Contains("capdcx_valueaddedtaxpercentage"))
            {
                vatPercentageAsWholeNumber = (decimal)vatEntity.Attributes["capdcx_valueaddedtaxpercentage"];
            }
            
            decimal vatPercentage = vatPercentageAsWholeNumber / 100;
            return vatPercentage;
        }
```

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
malliendk

Comment: I didn't check the whole code, but this is definitely an error
Guid vatId = (Guid)quoteLine.Attributes["capdcx_valueaddedtax"];
I assume that field is a lookup and you need to cast it as EntityReference, something like
EntityReference vatRef = quoteLine.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("capdcx_valueaddedtax");
if (vatRef == null) { /* logic to handle if the lookup is empty */ }
else { 
Guid vatId = vatRef.Id;
// rest of your code
}
hope it helps